# PHP - I need to call 2 php functions via url parameter - but how?

Tags: php, function, call

I have to call an old PHP function with PC1 encryption and unfortunately I have no instructions or example, only the PHP file - and no PHP know how :( :(

Can someone help me how to call the encrypt and decrypt function via URL-parameter? I only need to show/print the encrypted or decrypted result.

This is the old found code:

```
    <?
    //class to encrypt and decrypt according to the "PC1" algorithm
      // I. Verburgh 2007
    class PC1 {
        var $pkax;
        var $pkbx;
        var $pkcx;
        var $pkdx;
        var $pksi;
        var $pktmp;
        var $x1a2;
        var $pkres;
        var $pki;
        var $inter;
        var $cfc;
        var $cfd;
        var $compte;
        var $x1a0;
          var $cle;
        var $pkc;
        var $plainlen;
        var $ascipherlen;
        var $plainText;
        var $ascCipherText;


        function PC1() {
        }

        function pkfin() {
            for ($j=0;$j<16;$j++) {
                $this->cle[$j] = "";
            }
            for ($j=0;$j<8;$j++) {
                $this->x1a0[$j] = 0;
            }
            $this->pkax = 0;
            $this->pkbx = 0;
            $this->pkcx = 0;
            $this->pkdx = 0;
            $this->pksi = 0;
            $this->pktmp = 0;
            $this->x1a2 = 0;
            $this->pkres = 0;
            $this->pki = 0;
            $this->inter = 0;
            $this->cfc = 0;
            $this->cfd = 0;
            $this->compte = 0;
            $this->pkc = 0;
        }

        function pkcode() {
            $this->pkdx = $this->x1a2 + $this->pki;
            $this->pkax = $this->x1a0[$this->pki];
            $this->pkcx = 0x015a;
            $this->pkbx = 0x4e35;
            $this->pktmp = $this->pkax;
            $this->pkax = $this->pksi;
            $this->pksi = $this->pktmp;
            $this->pktmp = $this->pkax;
            $this->pkax = $this->pkdx;
            $this->pkdx = $this->pktmp;
            if ($this->pkax != 0)   {
                $this->pkax = $this->wordmultiply($this->pkax, $this->pkbx);
            }
            $this->pktmp = $this->pkax;
            $this->pkax = $this->pkcx;
            $this->pkcx = $this->pktmp;
            if ($this->pkax != 0)   {
                $this->pkax = $this->wordmultiply($this->pkax, $this->pksi);
                $this->pkcx = $this->wordsum($this->pkax, $this->pkcx);
            }
            $this->pktmp = $this->pkax;
            $this->pkax = $this->pksi;
            $this->pksi = $this->pktmp;
            $this->pkax = $this->wordmultiply($this->pkax, $this->pkbx);
            $this->pkdx = $this->wordsum($this->pkcx, $this->pkdx);
            $this->pkax = $this->wordsum($this->pkax, 1);
            $this->x1a2 = $this->pkdx;
            $this->x1a0[$this->pki] = $this->pkax;
            $this->pkres = $this->wordxor($this->pkax, $this->pkdx);
            $this->pki++;
        }

        function wordmultiply($value1, $value2) {
            if (is_numeric($value1) && is_numeric($value2))
                $product = (($value1 * $value2) % 65536);
            else {
                $product = 0;
                echo "error with wordmulitply<br />";
            }
            return $product;
        }

        function wordsum($value1, $value2) {
            $sum = (($value1 + $value2) % 65536);
            return $sum;
        }

        function wordminus($value1, $value2) {
            $minus = (($value1 - $value2) % 65536);
            return $minus;
        }

        function wordxor($value1, $value2) {
            $outcome = (($value1 ^ $value2) % 65536);
            return $outcome;
        }

        function pkassemble() {
            $this->x1a0[0] = $this->wordsum($this->wordmultiply(ord($this->cle[0]), 256), ord($this->cle[1]));
            $this->pkcode();
            $this->inter = $this->pkres;

            $this->x1a0[1] = $this->wordxor($this->x1a0[0], $this->wordsum($this->wordmultiply(ord($this->cle[2]), 256), ord($this->cle[3])));
            $this->pkcode();
            $this->inter = $this->wordxor($this->inter, $this->pkres);

            $this->x1a0[2] = $this->wordxor($this->x1a0[1], $this->wordsum($this->wordmultiply(ord($this->cle[4]), 256), ord($this->cle[5])));
            $this->pkcode();
            $this->inter = $this->wordxor($this->inter, $this->pkres);

            $this->x1a0[3] = $this->wordxor($this->x1a0[2], $this->wordsum($this->wordmultiply(ord($this->cle[6]), 256), ord($this->cle[7])));
            $this->pkcode();
            $this->inter = $this->wordxor($this->inter, $this->pkres);

            $this->x1a0[4] = $this->wordxor($this->x1a0[3], $this->wordsum($this->wordmultiply(ord($this->cle[8]), 256), ord($this->cle[9])));
            $this->pkcode();
            $this->inter = $this->wordxor($this->inter, $this->pkres);

            $this->x1a0[5] = $this->wordxor($this->x1a0[4], $this->wordsum($this->wordmultiply(ord($this->cle[10]), 256), ord($this->cle[11])));
            $this->pkcode();
            $this->inter = $this->wordxor($this->inter, $this->pkres);

            $this->x1a0[6] = $this->wordxor($this->x1a0[5], $this->wordsum($this->wordmultiply(ord($this->cle[12]), 256), ord($this->cle[13])));
            $this->pkcode();
            $this->inter = $this->wordxor($this->inter, $this->pkres);

            $this->x1a0[7] = $this->wordxor($this->x1a0[6], $this->wordsum($this->wordmultiply(ord($this->cle[14]), 256), ord($this->cle[15])));
            $this->pkcode();
            $this->inter = $this->wordxor($this->inter, $this->pkres);

            $this->pki=0;
        }

        function encrypt($in, $key) {
            $this->pkfin();
            $this->k = 0;
            $this->plainlen = strlen($in);
            for ($count=0;$count<16;$count++) {
                if (isset($key[$count]))
                    $this->cle[$count] = $key[$count];
            }
            for ($count=0;$count<$this->plainlen;$count++) {
                $this->pkc = ord($in[$count]);
                $this->pkassemble();

                $this->cfc = $this->inter >> 8;
                $this->cfd = $this->inter & 255;

                for ($this->compte=0;$this->compte<sizeof($this->cle);$this->compte++) {
                    $this->cle[$this->compte] = chr($this->wordxor(ord($this->cle[$this->compte]), $this->pkc));
                }
                $this->pkc = $this->wordxor($this->pkc, ($this->wordxor($this->cfc, $this->cfd)));

                $this->pkd = ($this->pkc >> 4);
                $this->pke = ($this->pkc & 15);
                $this->ascCipherText[$this->k] = $this->wordsum(0x61, $this->pkd);
                $this->k++;
                $this->ascCipherText[$this->k] = $this->wordsum(0x61, $this->pke);
                $this->k++;
            }
            $this->ascCipherText = array_map("chr", $this->ascCipherText);
            return implode("", $this->ascCipherText);

        }

        function decrypt($in, $key) {
            $this->pkfin();
            $return = "";
            for ($count=0;$count<16;$count++) {
                if (isset($key[$count]))
                    $this->cle[$count] = $key[$count];
                else
                    $this->cle[$count] = "";
            }
            $this->pksi = 0;
            $this->x1a2 = 0;
            $d = 0;
            $e = 0;
            $i = 0;
            $j = 0;
            $l = 0;

            $len = strlen($in);
            while ($j < $len) {
              $rep = $in[$j];
                switch($rep) {
                    case "a": {
                        $d = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "b": {
                        $d = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "c": {
                        $d = 2;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "d": {
                        $d = 3;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "e": {
                        $d = 4;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "f": {
                        $d = 5;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "g": {
                        $d = 6;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "h": {
                        $d = 7;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "i": {
                        $d = 8;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "j": {
                        $d = 9;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "k": {
                        $d = 10;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "l": {
                        $d = 11;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "m": {
                        $d = 12;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "n": {
                        $d = 13;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "o": {
                        $d = 14;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "p": {
                        $d = 15;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                $d = $d << 4;
                $j++;

                $rep = $in[$j];
                switch($rep) {
                    case "a": {
                        $e = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "b": {
                        $e = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "c": {
                        $e = 2;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "d": {
                        $e = 3;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "e": {
                        $e = 4;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "f": {
                        $e = 5;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "g": {
                        $e = 6;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "h": {
                        $e = 7;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "i": {
                        $e = 8;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "j": {
                        $e = 9;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "k": {
                        $e = 10;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "l": {
                        $e = 11;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "m": {
                        $e = 12;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "n": {
                        $e = 13;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "o": {
                        $e = 14;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "p": {
                        $e = 15;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            $c = $d + $e;
                $this->pkassemble();

                $this->cfc = $this->inter >> 8;
                $this->cfd = $this->inter & 255;

            $c = $this->wordxor($c, ($this->wordxor($this->cfc, $this->cfd)));

            for ($compte=0;$compte<16;$compte++)
              $this->cle[$compte] = chr($this->wordxor(ord($this->cle[$compte]), $c));
            $return = $return.chr($c);
            $j++;
                $l++;
            }
            return $return;
        }
    }

    ?>
```

What I tried was something like this

```
    public function index()
    {
        var $test;
        $test = encrypt("Hallo","nhifgbcnlfglffmh");
        echo test;
    }

    $app = new PC1();
    $app->index();
```

But I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR in....
I think the return implode does no return a string?

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR in...` look at the line in the file that the error message tells you to and you'll find the problem.

Comment: instead of $app->index() try  $test = $app->encrypt("Hallo","nhifgbcnlfglffmh");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is all in a class you first need to call the class

```
$app = new PC1();
```

Afther that you can call the functions inside that class:

```
$test = $app->encrypt("Hallo","nhifgbcnlfglffmh");
```

For the function to work as a URL param you could do the following:
URL: `example.com?encrypt=Hallo`

In the php page where it links to check for the `$_GET` so:

```
<?php
$app = new PC1();
if( !empty( $_GET['encrypt'] ) {
  $encrypt = $_GET['encrypt'];
  var_dump($app->encrypt($encrypt, "nhifgbcnlfglffmh"));
} elseif ( !empty( $_GET['decrypt'] ) ) {
  $decrypt = $_GET['decrypt'];
  var_dump($app->decrypt($decrypt, "nhifgbcnlfglffmh"));
}
```

Comment: Oh cool, thank you for your fast answer!
I tried to extend this at the top of the file but get now error 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in T:\xampp\htdocs\pc1.php on line 27

line 27 is: $app = new PC1();

Comment: It's easier to make a new file. In that new file include the pc1.php file or what the file is named where the class is in. Then afther that use the other functions. It will be cleaner and easier to maintain. So basically only have the class in one file and other functions in other files

Comment: Sorry, I had to put this code part and the end outside the class and there was missing only a ")" behind ['encrypt'] ) - now it works without error, thank you so much!